why am I getting "Uncaught TypeError: event.composedPath is not a function"
Below is a basic JQuery code, and I am getting an error I can't explain.
$(window).on('click', function(event) {

    console.log(event.currentTarget);
    console.log(event.target);
    event.composedPath().forEach((affected) => console.log(affected));
});

The event.currentTarget logs as expected, as does the event.target.
But the composedPath() method call fails with an error:

Uncaught TypeError: event.composedPath is not a function

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong, or think of any reason for the error? Hopefully, I am missing something obvious.

https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

jQuery's event system normalizes the event object according to W3C standards. The event object is guaranteed to be passed to the event handler. Most properties from the original event are copied over and normalized to the new event object.

In this case, the jQuery event does not contain composedPath so you need to access the originalEvent


$(window).on('click', function(event) {
  console.log(event.composedPath); // jQuery
  if (event.originalEvent && typeof event.originalEvent.composedPath === 'function') {
    console.log(event.originalEvent.composedPath);
  } else {
    console.log('composedPath is not available');
  }
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




Thank you @mplungjan that was exactly the issue. Silly me.

@RoryLynch Please see updated answer which shows you how to use it anyway
